# htaccess for url containning specific word

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website with URLs like `/product-category/clothing/accessories/?filter_color=yellow` now I want to rewrite these kinds of URLs to `/index.php/product-category/clothing/accessories/?filter_color=yellow` in fact, I want to add a rewrite rule in my htaccess that if the URL contains `product-category` and does not contain `index.php` then rewrite the `index.php` at the beginning of the URL. For this purpose I have developed the following code:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} product-category
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

But it does not work correctly. First, it adds `index.php` to all of the URLs and then it adds an extra `/` when `/index.php` already exists in the URL

Here is the complete .htaccess file:

[htaccess](https://pastebin.com/mgMTN2A0)

Comment: "First, it adds `index.php` to all of the URLs and then it adds an extra `/` when `/index.php` already exists in the URL" - Those directives alone won't do that. It's likely you have a conflict with other directives in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I have attached the file to question body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^product-category/.* /index.php/$0 [L,NC]
```

Comment: this changes `/product/single/` to `/index.php//product/single/` beside this type of URL should not be modified because it does not contain the word `product-category`

Comment: No that's not correct. You can see this rule is **only matching** URI starting with `/product-category/`

Comment: I have included htaccess file to the question body

Comment: @user435245 You've put the directive in the wrong place... it should go near the top, _before_ the "WordPress" code block. By placing it at the very end of the `.htaccess` file it's not going to do _anything_?! So, it's a mystery where `/index.php//product/single/` would be coming from?

Comment: Is this WordPress?

Comment: Yes it is WordPress

Comment: Ok so usually internal rewrite rules don't work well with WP because it uses REQUEST_URI variable in PHP which doesn't change with these rules